Windows SMB and NIC RSS
I trying to resolve an issue with SMB and RSS on my Windows 10 Pro.
I try to figure out how SMB detects if NIC supports RSS and uses Multichannel to decrease CPU single-core utilization.
I have a case where a 2.5Gbit Intel NIC (i226-V) is installed, and the transfer from the server is not as expected.
* Transfer to a server (Linux Samba) ~280 MB/s - this is expected.
* Transfer from a server ~130 MB/s - something is wrong.

I looked into task manager and CPU utilization for a single core is 100% (Core i9-9900k). This is probably the reason why transfer from serve is so low, single CPU core was unable to process more data than 1.3 Gbit/s (too many IRQs maybe)
The first thing was to use Jumbo Frames - it helped and now both download and upload are about 290 MB/s and CPU single-core utilization is about 50%. But I heard lots of cons about Jumbo Frames so I think that this could not be a perfect solution.
I started digging and found that RSS can be a solution as it allows the use of SMB Multichannel by dividing CPU loads into more cores. If for example 4 connections instead of one are used and each connection uses its own Receive Queue that could be processed on different CPU cores it splits utilization by 4 cores and in theory, 25% of each core will be used.
But looks like Intel removed RSS support for i226-V from the latest driver.
I found sets of regs keys that in theory should reenable RSS and I added them to the register.
Now Windows reports RSS for NIC
Get-NetAdapterRss

Name                                            : Ethernet
InterfaceDescription                            : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
Enabled                                         : True
NumberOfReceiveQueues                           : 2
Profile                                         : Closest
BaseProcessor: [Group:Number]                   : 0:0
MaxProcessor: [Group:Number]                    : 0:14
MaxProcessors                                   : 4
RssProcessorArray: [Group:Number/NUMA Distance] : 0:0/0  0:2/0  0:4/0  0:6/0  0:8/0  0:10/0  0:12/0  0:14/0
IndirectionTable: [Group:Number]                :

Name                                            : Ethernet 2.5Gbit
InterfaceDescription                            : Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I226-V
Enabled                                         : True
NumberOfReceiveQueues                           : 4
Profile                                         : NUMAStatic
BaseProcessor: [Group:Number]                   : 0:0
MaxProcessor: [Group:Number]                    : 0:14
MaxProcessors                                   : 4
RssProcessorArray: [Group:Number/NUMA Distance] : 0:0/0  0:2/0  0:4/0  0:6/0  0:8/0  0:10/0  0:12/0  0:14/0
IndirectionTable: [Group:Number] :

But SMB still reports all NICS as no RSS capable
Get-SmbClientNetworkInterface

Interface Index RSS Capable RDMA Capable Speed    IpAddresses                              Friendly Name
--------------- ----------- ------------ -----    -----------                              -------------
10              False       False        0  bps   {fe80::1024:1a7:103a:f7bc}               Ethernet
3               False       False        2.5 Gbps {fe80::38a4:cbfd:a9aa:fa50, 192.168.0.2} Ethernet 2.5Gbit
21              False       False        1 Gbps   {fe80::8844:d974:756:3129, 192.168.56.1} VirtualBox Host-Only Network
16              False       False        3 Mbps   {fe80::98ea:7ea6:c8aa:feb1}              Połączenie sieciowe Bluetooth 4

So I wonder how SMB code detects RSS. Does it use a driver call to check RSS support, the driver for i226-V does not implement RSS and those settings in the registry do nothing, or Windows 10 Pro has disabled RSS, and even if NIC reports it, SMB still uses a single connection. My previous setup used two 1Gbit NICs and SMB nicely utilized both of them and I observed ~220 MB/s transfer to and from the server so multichannel work.
I wonder if switching to Marvell Aquantia AQ113 helps, but at least I want to know if this card does not have a similar issue and if Windows SMB recognizes it as RSS capable and sets multiple connections to a server?

RSS is ancient. It's been around forever. Not including it would be stupid, as it cripples performance. The cheapest notebook adapter includes RSS. What does netsh show? https://edc.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/products/ethernet/adapters-and-devices-user-guide/receive-side-scaling/ Set-IntelNetAdapterSetting -Name "<adapter_name>" -DisplayName "Receive Side Scaling" -DisplayValue "Enabled"

Set-IntelNetAdapterSetting does not show this adapter only onboard i219V

Offloading is a hardware and driver feature. If the driver supports it you can configure it on the Advanced tab in the NIC properties.
As @GregAskew commented, Receive Side Scaling is ancient and pretty much a given. If SMB says it's not supported (by asking the driver) it's most likely been deactivated in the NIC properties.

My previous setup used two 1Gbit NICs and SMB nicely utilized both of them

That is NOT RSS. Receive Side Scaling distributes TCP processing for a particular connection to multiple CPUs/cores. Distributing traffic across multiple NICs is called multipathing or SMB3 Multichannel.
130 MB/s maximum throughput might also indicate a 1 Gbit/s link on the server, the client or somewhere in between.
